# Usage of @Component in case of inheritance

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 scenarios where I would like to understand/confirm the usage of `@Component`:

**Extending concrete class:**
I have a concrete super class A and its sub-class Aa in my web application. I have annotated with Aa with `@Component(value="aa")` and `@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)`. Also, I have annotated A class with `@Component(value="a")` and `@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)`.

My question -> I am only doing `applicationContext.getBean("aa")`. I can skip the annotations in A class (please correct me if I am wrong), **but I don't know why and how?** My understanding has been that if a class is not annotated with `@Component` or defined in bean configuration file then Spring doesn't handle its instance management.

**Abstract concrete class:**
Same scenario and question as above just that in this case super class is an abstract class.

Comment: Why are you using `getBean` anyway? The preferred way is injection. Also note that it's becoming more common to use `@Bean` methods in `@Configuration` classes instead of component-scanning.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the beans via beans in a config or via component annotations (Repo or controller or service). If not the bean is not contained in your application context container.

Comment: What they say above is true. if the base class is annotated it can be also injected the inherited one.

Answer (score 1):

`@Component` add a bean in the Spring registry. Then, you can retrieve this bean later.

If you don't use the bean, there is no need to add it to the bean registry.  (so just remove `@Component(value="a")` and `@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)` )

On your use case, you set a scope to SESSION. It means that every time you create a session, Spring will instantiate your class (A / Aa) and put it on the session. As it is an instance of the class you don't need the super class instance (A) to be able to create the Aa instance.

With A beeing abstract, it is exactly the same thing, except if you try to scan it for Spring to pick it, Spring will throws an error saying A cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your inputs. You are putting it like this that "it adds a bean in Spring registry" or it is in official documentation. Can you point me some reference where I can read about Spring registry?

Comment: "Spring registry" is something I use but is not real thing. It is more like "Bean storage" where bean managed by Spring are stored. Correct word should be ApplicationContext.

Comment: Ok. Please correct me on my understanding - if I am doing `applicationContext.getBean()` for my super class (whether concrete or abstract) then I need not to add any annotation or scope to it?

Comment: If you have `public abstract class A`  and `@Component public class Aa extends A` then `applicationContext.getBean(A.class)` will return an instance of Aa (which can be casted to A).

Comment: I don't think what you are saying in above comment is true, did you try? `applicationContext.getBean(A.class)` will throw exception saying no bean definition because Spring would have not registered that as a bean, you can do this only for `Aa`.

Comment: Just try, Spring is fine with that. Note that you can also do it with interface. You declare an interface, declare an implementation that you annotate with @Service / @Component / @Repository  then you can inject from Spring context by the interface name.    ( `interface TestService{...}`   `@Service class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {....}`  and use it via `@Autowired private TestService testService;` in another Spring managed bean )